# How to organize files by extension using a batch file

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I have many types of files spread around various directories on my laptop.  I would like to move the files to appropriate directories based on their filename extensions.  For example,  all image files to My Pictures, all document files to My Documents, etc.

I would like to create a batch file to do this.  I have only a little familiarity with DOS commands and no experience with batch files.  Can I get some general guidance on how to approach this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. More details are needed about what you are trying to do exactly. As it is, this is too vague to help you. Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. It may be helpful to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Comment: okay sorry, im trying to sort files by extension type. But I dont know how to set it all out in notepad, im sure theres more to it than                                                                      C:\Downloads

move *.mp3 Music
move *.jpg Pictures
move *.doc Documents

Comment: like I said above @CharlieRB my files and formats are everywhere on my laptop and copying and pasting the extention type dose nothing when i edit it as a batch file. what am i doing wrong here???

Comment: Just to clarify, is there a particular reason you're restricting the solution to a batch file?  Would any solution work that in one, or a limited number, of steps, recursed through your user directories and moved the files based on their extensions?  The lack of response is likely because the question seems overly broad or sounds like you're asking people to write a program for you.  If you are trying to write a batch file yourself and experiencing problems, add what you've tried to the question and people are more likely to help you solve specific problems.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the batch file you have so far. If you add the code to the question, someone may be able to help.

Comment: I've asked the same question before here on "Stack exchange" and still have no understanding of typing out the text in notepad to move formats?????

Comment: I already wrote down what I write down in notepad to move the formats in the second comment above starting at, C:\Downloads then underneath that I wrote move *.mp3 Music etc etc. OKAY for example I copied  and pasted some of my mp3 formats to my documents file in windows explorer of course you'll know what "my documents" are every windows person has the software in the pc. anyway then I typed in note pad move *.mp3 music underneath C;\Downloads. nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

You can create a batch file that moves all files with the given extension:

```
@echo off
move ./.%1 "%2"\
```

and save it as `ext.bat`

`%1` and `%2` are parameters that stand for the first and second arguments, that is the **extension** and the **folder** respectively.

For instance executing:

```
ext mp3 "C:\Users\John Doe\Music"
```

would move all the files in the current directory with `mp3` extension to the specified (relative or absolute) path, that is `Music` folder of the user `John Doe` here.